# What is the type parameter on the NRF24NetworkHeader member

Tags: library, nrf24l01+

[Link of the member](http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24Network/structRF24NetworkHeader.html#a99e675f31589d72cf2fe036e77988026)
What is the character parameter in the above member of the class NRF24Network 
I cannot understand the use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to identify the type of packet.  Apparently that code supports types of 0-127, and I guess (impossible to tell without digging into the code) that what you use them for is entirely up to you.  Basically it would typically define what is in the rest of the packet - again something which is up to you.

Comment: Yes but i have to put a char but it takes types 0-127. What does that mean

Comment: Hint: 'a' is 97. '8' is 56.  ASCII.

Comment: Oh now I understand. And for example if I want to parse rgb code I will send 3 packets with -for example- type r,g,b ?

Comment: Or one packet with 'c' for colour and three values in your packet...

Comment: Nice and one last question how can someone parse 3 values in one packet? Can that be achieved by sending 3 variable values or somehow else.

Comment: Use a struct and send them as one single compound variable.